# spark structured streaming from kinesis to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-kinesis, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running a spark structured streaming query on a kinesis stream source. 
It reads (without time trigger) from kinesis, compute an aggregation, and push the result (outputMode "update") using a custom dynamodb sink.

spark version : 2.1.1 and kinesis source lib : https://github.com/maropu/spark-kinesis-sql-asl

I want to process 1 500 events by seconds (I produce fake events using KinesisDataGenerator :https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/web/producer.html)

Everything runs on aws EMR, via spark shell (it's a POC)

I did some tunning and arrived to theses parameters :

- 2 kinesis shards
- 2 000 dynamodb WCUs
- 1 single cluster node m4.4xlarge (16 cpu 64 go)

Everything runs fine during around half one hour, and it seems that suddenly some delay happens, each batch take more and more time to proceed, until having ProvisionedThroughputExceededException (number of reads exceed the limit)

I have no problem with dynamodb (WCUs peaks around 1500 with 2000 provisionning, no throttled write requests)

Kinesis reads are quite stable, but as long as the process slow down, more and more events are read at the same time from kinesis, and it crashes.

I added until 8 shards and same thing occurs, I only win a little time before have the ProvisionedThroughputExceededException (nb : instance cpus count is > than number of kinesis shards)

I changed my kinesis loading throughput from 500 to 1500 events/sec and same thing happens about half on hour.

Using a bigger instance produce the same results...
I tried with fewer kind of events (100 distinct random events on input vs 600 000 distinct ones) : same thing

Concerning the dynamodb sink : a second aggregation is computed on the query stream result (because spark structured streaming doesn't allow multiple aggregations).

The end to end process consist in : "Read from kinesis -> Streamming query (aggregation 1) -> Dynamodb Sink (aggregation 2 + dynamodb inserts)".  I use "update" outputMode so that only rows updated from the result table are sent to the sink.

I added some logs in the addBatch method of the sink :

- number of input rows (result of streaming query)
- number of insert requests (resultt of streaming query after my second aggreation, second count is always equals or below the first one)
- elapsed time for the whole sink process.

For a kinesis loading of 500 events / second, I got something like that :

```
....
addBatch(4) -> input rows 3574 output insertRequests 3449                       
addBatch(4) -> Elapsed time: 6.983257993seconds
addBatch(5) -> input rows 4052 output insertRequests 3909                       
addBatch(5) -> Elapsed time: 5.83499691seconds
addBatch(6) -> input rows 2745 output insertRequests 2657                       
addBatch(6) -> Elapsed time: 4.879952608seconds
addBatch(7) -> input rows 3081 output insertRequests 2969                       
addBatch(7) -> Elapsed time: 3.939775103seconds
addBatch(8) -> input rows 2010 output insertRequests 1925                       
addBatch(8) -> Elapsed time: 5.151868592seconds
addBatch(9) -> input rows 2977 output insertRequests 2869                       
addBatch(9) -> Elapsed time: 4.722617963seconds
addBatch(10) -> input rows 2530 output insertRequests 2448                      
addBatch(10) -> Elapsed time: 5.562205997seconds
....
addBatch(100) -> input rows 2996 output insertRequests 2864                     
addBatch(100) -> Elapsed time: 4.873477912seconds
addBatch(101) -> input rows 2535 output insertRequests 2458                     
addBatch(101) -> Elapsed time: 4.284861452seconds
addBatch(102) -> input rows 2477 output insertRequests 2388                     
addBatch(102) -> Elapsed time: 5.174349386seconds
addBatch(103) -> input rows 3942 output insertRequests 3791                     
addBatch(103) -> Elapsed time: 4.957703028seconds
addBatch(104) -> input rows 3490 output insertRequests 3366                     
addBatch(104) -> Elapsed time: 8.761093424seconds
.....
addBatch(224) -> Elapsed time: 4.475522722seconds
addBatch(225) -> input rows 2508 output insertRequests 2406                     
addBatch(225) -> Elapsed time: 5.819129461seconds
addBatch(226) -> input rows 3009 output insertRequests 2914                     
addBatch(226) -> Elapsed time: 10.994768506seconds
addBatch(227) -> input rows 4755 output insertRequests 4557                     
addBatch(227) -> Elapsed time: 11.034992149seconds
addBatch(228) -> input rows 6739 output insertRequests 6397                     
addBatch(228) -> Elapsed time: 12.409657235seconds
addBatch(229) -> input rows 5049 output insertRequests 4888                     
addBatch(229) -> Elapsed time: 12.584365428seconds
addBatch(230) -> input rows 7758 output insertRequests 7485                     
addBatch(230) -> Elapsed time: 18.631239639seconds
addBatch(231) -> input rows 9554 output insertRequests 9030                     
addBatch(231) -> Elapsed time: 18.426685181seconds
addBatch(232) -> input rows 8822 output insertRequests 8382                     
addBatch(232) -> Elapsed time: 15.920548608seconds
addBatch(233) -> input rows 9251 output insertRequests 8759                     
addBatch(233) -> Elapsed time: 19.984515183seconds
addBatch(234) -> input rows 10336 output insertRequests 9923                    
addBatch(234) -> Elapsed time: 20.487669168seconds
....
addBatch(247) -> Elapsed time: 25.539402107seconds
addBatch(248) -> input rows 12863 output insertRequests 12269                   
addBatch(248) -> Elapsed time: 27.541254374seconds
addBatch(249) -> input rows 13744 output insertRequests 13069
```

For a kinesis loading of 1 000 events / second, I got something like that :

```
....
addBatch(8) -> input rows 5247 output insertRequests 5023                       
addBatch(8) -> Elapsed time: 5.162705257seconds
addBatch(9) -> input rows 7484 output insertRequests 7106                       
addBatch(9) -> Elapsed time: 5.829125017seconds
....
addBatch(19) -> input rows 13981 output insertRequests 13069                    
addBatch(19) -> Elapsed time: 8.643140194seconds
addBatch(20) -> input rows 14998 output insertRequests 13997                    
addBatch(20) -> Elapsed time: 8.930952027seconds
....
addBatch(70) -> input rows 13442 output insertRequests 12626                    
addBatch(70) -> Elapsed time: 7.891013506seconds
....
addBatch(146) -> Elapsed time: 11.865784296seconds
addBatch(147) -> input rows 19489 output insertRequests 17976                   
addBatch(147) -> Elapsed time: 11.57164558seconds
addBatch(148) -> input rows 18229 output insertRequests 16863                   
addBatch(148) -> Elapsed time: 12.319194939seconds
addBatch(149) -> input rows 20976 output insertRequests 19298                   
addBatch(149) -> Elapsed time: 13.426055377seconds
addBatch(150) -> input rows 21017 output insertRequests 19325                   
addBatch(150) -> Elapsed time: 12.750020974seconds
addBatch(151) -> input rows 19494 output insertRequests 17962                   
addBatch(151) -> Elapsed time: 11.652468707seconds
....
addBatch(180) -> input rows 22960 output insertRequests 21013                   
addBatch(180) -> Elapsed time: 15.388526621seconds
addBatch(181) -> input rows 22492 output insertRequests 20555                   
addBatch(181) -> Elapsed time: 14.175100191seconds
addBatch(182) -> input rows 22964 output insertRequests 21039                   
addBatch(182) -> Elapsed time: 16.682608754seconds
```

I can't find why my process is delayed. 
Why first batches are quite stable and why it begins to take more and more time, until crashing around half an hour despite the variation of parameters tested (instance size, number of kinesis shards...).

Here are some questions on spark structured streaming :

- Is the unbounded table increasing constantly in memory ?
- Is it the same for the result table ?
- Is there a way to limit the number of records reads on the kinesis stream ? I tried with time trigger but same thing happens, when there is delay everything is read until "now".
- Is the increasing result table that slow down the process ? Searching for update rows in it takes more and more time ?

What point am I missing ?

Thanks,

Philippe